# UserNotificationListener: The remote procedure call failed

Tags: c#, wpf

I could not figure out why I get error on second line. On some PC everything works on other not.

I use WPF with Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts 10.0.22621.755 installed.

```
UserNotificationListener notifiacationListener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
notifiacationListener.NotificationChanged += Listener_NotificationChanged;
```

**System.Exception: 'The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)'**

I can request notification access without any trouble, but when I try to subscribe I will get the error.

```
UserNotificationListener notifiacationListener = UserNotificationListener.Current;
if (notifiacationListener.GetAccessStatus() == UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
     notifiacationListener.NotificationChanged += Listener_NotificationChanged;   
}
```

I also tried called this before notification usage.

```
notificationStatus = await notifiacationListener.RequestAccessAsync()
```

Comment: Check Event Viewer on Listener Machine for more info on the exception.

Comment: oh my god I have the same exact problem. not sure what the reason for this is, but considering this question is the only resource I could find on the internet relating to this issue I'm starting to wonder if this could be an issue with a recent Windows release? I'm running Windows 11 22H2 OS Build 22621.1037 Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22638.1000.0

Comment: @Bluskript Do you have single language Windows edition? I found that this issue appers on single language version. I use Windows Pro and do not have such issue on it.

Comment: I'm on pro and this issue still appears.

Comment: @steam3d were you on insiders when this issue started happening? Are you on insiders now when its working?

Comment: @Bluskript No. I installed fresh one language edition Windows 10 20h2 from microsoft.com.

Comment: yeah, I did a fresh install and it fixed it too.. No matter how much I tried to reset it wouldn't fix it, only a full format and reinstall solved the issue, and even then it didnt work until I waited 30 minutes and then it magically started working. What an unreliable API.